# does the delete operator always return true if the object is defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```
console.log(
   delete ({a: true}['a'])
);
```

that will log `true`.
But so will this:

```
 console.log(
    delete ({a: true}['b'])
 );
```

I am just trying to use a one-liner to return whether a key was present in the object before it was deleted.

It looks like I have to do this instead?

```
  const v = {a: true};
  console.log(('b' in v) && delete v['b']);
```

why doesn't the `delete` operator return false if `'b'` is not present in the object?

Comment: I would recommend  using `'b' in v` instead of `v['b']`

Comment: yep in this case, I agree, although that wasn't necessarily the nature of the question